# Ignore debounce when we switch files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

I have made a very very basic [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fmAlKBwaATFgGuj2ReQr?p=preview), which mimics what happens with a text editor: we could switch between `file1` and `file2` and edit their content. Modifying the content will fire `changeFile`, but I want to set a `debounce`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
        <input class="item" ng-model="file.name" ng-click="goFile(file)" ng-readonly="true" style="border: none; cursor: pointer"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <textarea ng-change="changeFile(file)" ng-model="file.body" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"></textarea>
    <div id="console">Recorded:<br/></div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
      app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.files = [{name: "file1", body: "body1"}, {name: "file2", body: "body2"}]
        $scope.file = $scope.files[0]

        $scope.goFile = function (file) {
          $scope.file = file
        }

        $scope.changeFile = function (file) {
          document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += file.body + "<br/>"
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem here is that, just after modifying the content of a file, very quickly if we switch to the other file, the modification will not be taken into account; it will not be displayed in the console. That's not what I wanted; I would hope switching to another file fires `changeFile` no matter if `debounce` finishes or not.

Does anyone know how to amend the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is change the [`debounce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) to a [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) as the problem with the `debounce` is that it won't apply the value to the scope until the time is up.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/W6z5BmMYHzcUWbW73fyF?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.files = [{
    name: "file1",
    body: "body1"
  }, {
    name: "file2",
    body: "body2"
  }]
  $scope.file = $scope.files[0]

  $scope.goFile = function(file) {
    $scope.file = file
    $scope.selectedItem = file
  }

  $scope.changeFile = function(file, time) {
    if (file.timeout) {
      $timeout.cancel(file.timeout);
    }
    file.timeout = $timeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += file.body + "<br/>"
      console.log(file.name + " changed: " + file.body);
    }, time)

  }

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="contentCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index" ng-class="{selected : selectedItem === file}">
    <input class="item" ng-model="file.name" ng-click="goFile(file)" ng-readonly="true" style="border: none; cursor: pointer" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <textarea ng-change="changeFile(file,2000)" ng-model="file.body"></textarea>
  <div id="console">Recorded:<br/></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've added the ability to pass through the amount of time you'd like to debounce by so that you can add one line to the `$scope.changeFile` function so it will update straight away when changing files.

Comment: One problem of your solution is that, it always fires `changeFile` when we switch files, even though there is no content change. Do you have any idea to improve this efficiently?

Comment: @SoftTimur You can remove `$scope.changeFile($scope.file, 0);` from `$scope.goFile` but this will mean there will be a delay if you've changed the value and then changed the file quickly

Comment: Great... [This solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/UbqMAkdkyHhBYxcoMVNM?p=preview) is exactly what I want. So it fires `changeFile` only when there is no new change for 2 seconds, and all the previous changes in all the files will be taken into account... Thank you...

Comment: @SoftTimur No problem, I've updated the code in the question to remove that line.

Comment: Wait... I think I still need one kind of outputs: I want to log `file1 changed: body1abc`, `file2 changed body2efg`, `file1 changed body1abcdefg`, `file2 changed body2efghijk`, etc... A line of log is generated when 2 seconds ends after a change OR a switching of files after a change. And I don't want a log if there is just a switching of files without any change. Could you help me achieve that? Delay is not a problem, but I hope no log is missing...

Comment: Yeah, I can have a quick look into it.

Comment: It is almost there... But when you switch + modify + switch + modify + ... you will see there is a bug... hard to describe but I think you could see the bug...

Comment: @SoftTimur It still has the delay but should be working now. Yes I saw what that bug was :) it should no longer overwrite the different files timeout, it will still add a 2 second timeout if you switch fast enough though